# Rotating a PNG Image in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, image, rotation, png

I am quite new to C++.

I have a PNG image which I am trying to rotate by 180 degrees.

The image is to be saved as a new file.

I have wrote out a bit of code but hit a brick wall, any tips for how to continue would be appreciated. Code so far is below, thanks in advance.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include "ImageHandle.h"

using namespace std;

void rotatedImage (unsigned PixelGrid[WIDTH][HEIGHT]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
const char LogoFile[] = "Airplane.png";

unsigned PixelGrid[WIDTH][HEIGHT];     // Image loaded from file

// If the file cannot be loaded ...
if (!loadImage(PixelGrid, LogoFile))
{
    // Display an error message
    cout << "Error loading file \"" << LogoFile << "\"" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "File \"" << LogoFile << "\" opened successfully" << endl;

    // Demo of use of saveImage - to create a copy as "Airplane.png"
    // This should be modified to save the new images as specified
    if (saveImage(PixelGrid, "AirplaneCopy.png"))
    {
        cout << "File \"AirplaneCopy.png\" saved successfully" << 
endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Could not save \"AirplaneCopy.png\"" << endl;
    }
}

rotatedImage(PixelGrid);

{
    if (saveImage(PixelGrid, "AirplaneRotated.png"))
    {
        cout << "\nFile\"AirplaneRotated.png\" saved successfully" << 
endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nCould not save \"AirplaneRotated.png\"" << endl;
    }
}

return a.exec();
}

void rotatedImage (unsigned PixelGrid[WIDTH][HEIGHT])
{
int row;
int col;

for (row = 0; row < WIDTH; row++)
{
    for (col = 0; col < HEIGHT; col++)
    {
        PixelGrid[row][col] = 
    }
}
}
```

Thanks again.

Comment: Do you want to rotate it in 45 degrees? 180?

Comment: If you use Qt, you should take a look at QImage::transformed() function.

Comment: @JLewis Well - In stack overflow we want to have 1 question per post - so I recommend you to open new question and I will take a look. If my post helped you - please mark it as accepted (the "v" mark at the left of my post) so other may use it

Comment: Please do not vandalise your posts, you are invalidating the work of those that helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need it rotate a picture 180 degree, I guess you can use simple loop on half the picture and swap in each iteration the position on 1 pair of pixels.

Let look at pixel at position `(i,j)` - where should it be after the rotation? because it is 180, it should be at `(WIDTH - i, HEIGHT -j)` so your `rotatedImage` should look like:

```
void rotatedImage (unsigned PixelGrid[WIDTH][HEIGHT])
{
    int row;
    int col;

    for (row = 0; row < WIDTH/2; row++)// because you only have to loop on half the image
    {
        for (col = 0; col < HEIGHT; col++) 
        {
            unsigned temp = PixelGrid[row][col];
            PixelGrid[row][col] = PixelGrid[WIDTH - row][HEIGHT - col];
            PixelGrid[WIDTH - row][HEIGHT - col] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

I am not `c++` expert so I hope I have none syntax error and I never check that so beware from array out of index I may missed

Comment: @Damien - I didn't crop anything AFAIK

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to do for 180 degrees rotation.

You need to flip the array like this.

```
Original           Flipped rows      and Finally Flipped cols

[0][0 , 1, 2]      [2][0, 1, 2]    [2][2, 1, 0]

[1][0 , 1, 2]      [1][0, 1, 2]    [1][2, 1, 0]

[2][0 , 1, 2]      [0][0, 1, 2]    [0][2, 1, 0]
```

You need only to flip the rows and cols in the other direction in the array.